# How to use Python package on Mac after pip install?

Tags: python, macos, pip

I'm trying to install **plistutils** and use it in terminale, I tried to do this:

1. `brew install python`
2. `pip install plistutils`
3. ???

I found that it's located in

> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plistutils/

- **init**.py
- **pycache**
- alias.py
- bookmark.py
- nskeyedarchiver.py
- plistparser.py
- utils.py

How can I use `plistutils` from the terminal? Something like this:

```
atikhonov: plistutils -d -i file.plist
```

Comment: `python3.7 -m plistutils <command line args>`

Comment: @Mark No module named plistutils.__main__; 'plistutils' is a package and cannot be directly executed

Comment: This library doesn't define any executables, as can be seen in [its setup script](https://github.com/strozfriedberg/plistutils/blob/master/setup.py). If you need an executable script, you have to write one yourself (or find one somewhere). Take a look at the [readme](https://github.com/strozfriedberg/plistutils/blob/master/README.md) for sample snippets.

Comment: @hoefling thanks for explanation !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`plistutils`](https://github.com/strozfriedberg/plistutils) does not define any commands.  You can't use it from the terminal, only inside Python code.